# Way to host node project on IIS

Tags: node.js, angular, iis-7

I have been working on an Angular application with node. I succeeded in hosting Angular application to IIS but still needs to run node application manually in localhost using `npm run build`.

Now all I want is to host Node application on IIS so that I can directly use it in the project. I tried [IISNode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) but no success. Any way to do it without using IISNode?

And which is best practice, using a single project for Node and Angular application or create separate applications for both.